# GWT Throwing exception to client

Tags: gwt, exception, throw

Can someone show to throw exception to client in GWT.

in my serviceasync interface i am doing this as well in my service interface

```
void ActivateUserAccount(String ActivationCode,AsyncCallback <Boolean> Callback) throws AlreadyActivatedError;
```

in my serverimpl;

i am doing this to throw an exception

```
public Boolean ActivateUserAccount(String ActivationCode) throws AlreadyActivatedError
    {
....
throw new AlreadyActivatedError();
}
```

my exception is in the form:

```
public class AlreadyActivatedError extends Exception implements IsSerializable
{
    public AlreadyActivatedError()
    {
        super();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify your question?.. What was wrong with your current approach? Your exception that you throw at server side does not reach to gwt client .. Is this your problem?.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just to make everything clear: you can throw both checked (the ones extending `Exception`) and unchecked (extending `RuntimeException`) exceptions from the server to the client - as long as the exception is [serializable](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/tutorial/RPC.html#serialize). It is however recommended to throw checked exceptions, as they

> represent invalid conditions in areas outside the immediate control of the program (invalid user input, database problems, network outages, absent files).

In contrast, unchecked exceptions

> represent defects in the program (bugs) - often invalid arguments passed to a non-private method.

[Source](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=129)

As the [documentation states](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/tutorial/RPC.html#exceptions), the following conditions have to be fulfilled for an exception to be sent to the client:

- It has to extend `Exception` (note that `RuntimeException` does that).
- It has to be [serializable](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/tutorial/RPC.html#serialize). In short: implement `Serializable`, have a no-args constructor and have all the fields serializable.
- In your `*Service` interface you need to add a `throws` declaration to the method that can throw the exception. Note that you don't need to add the `throws` declaration to the `*Async` interface.

Once you have that set up, you'll be able to handle the exception in the `onFailure` method in your `AsyncCallback`.

Some code to show all the pieces together, based on examples from [the guide on the GWT site](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/tutorial/RPC.html):

#### DelistedException.java

```java
public class DelistedException extends Exception implements Serializable {

  private String symbol;

  // Note the no-args constructor
  // It can be protected so that only subclasses could use it
  // (because if they want to be serializable too, they'll need
  // a no-args constructor that calls the superclasses' no-args constructor...)
  protected DelistedException() {
  }

  public DelistedException(String symbol) {
    this.symbol = symbol;
  }

  public String getSymbol() {
    return this.symbol;
  }
}
```

#### StockPriceService.java

```java
@RemoteServiceRelativePath("stockPrices")
public interface StockPriceService extends RemoteService {
  StockPrice[] getPrices(String[] symbols) throws DelistedException;
}
```

#### StockPriceServiceAsync.java

```java
public interface StockPriceServiceAsync {
  void getPrices(String[] symbols, AsyncCallback<StockPrice[]> callback);
}
```

#### On the client side

```java
AsyncCallback<StockPrice[]> callback = new AsyncCallback<StockPrice[]>() {
  public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
    if (caught instanceof DelistedException) {
      // Do something with it
    } else {
      // Probably some unchecked exception,
      // show some generic error message
  }

  public void onSuccess(StockPrice[] result) {
    // Success!
  }
};

stockPriceService.getPrices(symbols, callback);
```

Answer (score 5):

Not sure why hilal's answer was accepted as it is completely false.

In order for the exceptions to reach the client's browser you **must** throw a [checked exception](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=129) that is `Serializable` and defined in the service interfaces.

If your service implementation throws a `RuntimeException` the web client will receive a generic 500 error messages as follows:

```
   [WARN] Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call
com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.UnexpectedException: Service method 'public abstract my.module.shared.Result my.module.client.service.Service.doSomething() throws my.module.shared.exception.MyCheckedException' threw an unexpected exception: my.module.shared.exception.AuthzRuntimeException: some authz message
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponseForFailure(RPC.java:389)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:579)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:208)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:362)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:729)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:49)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:324)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:505)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:843)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:647)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:211)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:380)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:395)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:488)
Caused by: my.module.shared.exception.AuthzRuntimeException: some authz message
    at my.module.shared.Authz.doSomeCheck(Authz.java:101)
    at my.module.server.ServiceImpl.doSomething(ServiceImpl.java:283)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:561)
    ... 22 more
[ERROR] 500 - POST /module/userService (127.0.0.1) 57 bytes
   Request headers
      Host: 127.0.0.1:8888
      User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0
      Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
      Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
      Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
      Referer: http://127.0.0.1:8888/foo.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997
      Cookie: worknet=7k8g41ulbl674dp865t180tji5
      Connection: keep-alive
      Cache-Control: no-cache
      X-GWT-Permutation: HostedMode
      X-GWT-Module-Base: http://127.0.0.1:8888/module/
      Content-Type: text/x-gwt-rpc; charset=utf-8
      Content-Length: 1076
      Pragma: no-cache
   Response headers
      Content-Type: text/plain
(RequestCallbackAdapter.java:209) 2013-10-18 13:16:56,966 [WARN ] Fail ""
com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.StatusCodeException: 500 The call failed on the server; see server log for details
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.RequestCallbackAdapter.onResponseReceived(RequestCallbackAdapter.java:209)
    at com.google.gwt.http.client.Request.fireOnResponseReceived(Request.java:258)
    at com.google.gwt.http.client.RequestBuilder$1.onReadyStateChange(RequestBuilder.java:412)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor40.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannelServer.java:338)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:219)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:571)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:279)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:242)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor37.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:293)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:547)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:364)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

GWT can only handle [unchecked exceptions](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html)(which means sent from server to client) which are not serialized that extends from [RuntimeException](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html). I don't know what `AlreadyActivatedError` is. If it is not RuntimeException it can't be sent to the client(browser)

Comment: Hilal, the opposite of what you said is true. Only checked exceptions generated on server side are sent to gwt layer. For uncheckted exception, you only get com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.StatusCodeException . You should correct your answer..

Comment: @Gursel start with new web project in eclipse. You can see IllegalArgumentException which extends from RuntimeExcetion which is unchecked exception

Comment: well, what is the relation to what I said.. I did not say that IllegalArgument exception is checkedException. What I said is only checked exceptions are propagated from server to gwt layer. You can check this easily.

Comment: so we say same thing but in different format. with writing "can handle" I mean that the exception should be runtime exception that can be handled and catch on the client side

Comment: Gursel, I am also confused by this answer being accepted as it is completely false.  I put some details in my answer about what shows up in the Jetty logs if you try to throw an unchecked RuntimeException from a service implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe also note that if your specific Exception does not have a standard constructor, the generic 500 error message will also be displayed because it is not possible to deserialize the exception. Sadly, the gwt compiler and dev-mode plugin will not always point this problem out explicitly.. (that's how i got here anyway)

So, in combination with what vinnyjames said (the exception must be Serializable and be defined in the (RPC) service's interface), i found that processing exceptions in gwt client code is not too complicated.